# Cannot connect to RDS using rdsutils.BuildAuthToken

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-rds

I followed every step in [the official documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/rds/rdsutils/#BuildAuthToken) and used the exact same code snippet.

When I replace the authToken with a hard-coded password, then the connection will become successful.

I have assigned the User Programmatic access, but no policies.

```
//Yes Env vars are available
//creating new credentials from environment variables
//AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID  and  AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
awsCreds := credentials.NewEnvCredentials()

//creating authentication token for the database connection
authToken, err := rdsutils.BuildAuthToken(dbEndpoint, awsRegion, dbUser, awsCreds)
if err != nil {
    Logger.LogFatal("Unable to build Authentication Token")
    log.Fatal("Unable to build Authentication Token")  //todo remove
}

//setting up TLS
mysql.RegisterTLSConfig("custom", &tls.Config{
    InsecureSkipVerify: true,
})

// Creating the MySQL DNS string for the DB connection
// user:password@protocol(endpoint)/dbname?<params>
dnsStr := fmt.Sprintf("%s:%s@tcp(%s:%s)/%s?tls=custom",
    dbUser, authToken, dbEndpoint,dbPort, dbName,
)
database, err = sql.Open("mysql", dnsStr)
```

I'm still trying to fix this. This is the error message I get:

```
error: ERROR: Error 1045: Access denied for user 'master'@'x.x.x.189' (using password: YES)
```

Comment: IAM Auth [seems to require an SSL connection to the db](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.IAMDBAuth.html).  It's not clear whether you are doing that.

Comment: What's the version of the AWS SDK you use? Seems like there was a related issue in SDK which fixed now https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/issues/1248

Comment: @JulieNoobie Can you post the connection error which you are seeing?

Comment: @Anuruddha Hey! I'm using the latest version. I'm pinging the connection and I receive an error. When I'm not using the authtoken, no error will be noticed.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot hey, I have not added TLS to the connection and I'm still getting this error: ERROR: Error 1045: Access denied for user 'master'@'x.x.x.189' (using password: YES)

Comment: Please help me :(

Comment: Same issue here, where you be able to resolve it?